# Dropdown Selection with different Aggregations

Tags: altair

I'm using the following code to select between two columns for the chart data. I would like to use a 'count' aggregation for the GrantType data and  a 'sum' aggregation for the 'AwardAmount'. Using transform_aggregate just seems to break the chart (chart is always empty) and I'm not sure how I would change the aggregation based on the input column anyway. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
input_selector = alt.binding_radio(
    options = ['GrantType', 'AwardAmount'],
    name="Display: "
)

input_param = alt.param(
    value='GrantType',
    bind=input_selector
)

radial_1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_arc(innerRadius=30, stroke='#fff').encode(
    theta = alt.Theta('input:Q', stack=True),
    radius = alt.Radius('input:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='sqrt', zero=True, rangeMin=20)),
    order = alt.Order('input:Q'),
    color = alt.Color(
        'GrantType:N', 
        sort=alt.EncodingSortField('GrantType', op='count', order='descending'),
        scale=alt.Scale(domain= funding_source_list, range= select_colors)
    )
).transform_calculate(
    input=f'datum[{input_param.name}]'
).add_params(input_param)
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data (ideally from the example gallery) so that someone can copy paste your code when troubleshooting?

Comment: In theory, any data with two columns, one nominal, one numeric, would work. Nominal column would replace 'GrantType', numeric column would replace 'AwardAmount'.

Here's a link for the exact data I'm using, but can't guarantee long-term validity of the link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LwqcXyr-wZYpdzDIXmgETdVvE3Xcoark/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense that any data would work, I'm just suggesting to make the example as simple as possible so that it is more likely that someone will be able to help out by easily copy pasting what you have and try it out themselves.